# How to set an env variable in Glassfish 2.1

Tags: java, glassfish

I want to deploy an application, that is currently deployed in Tomcat, in Glassfish version 2.1.

In the Tomcat server.xml I have an env variable defined in the server.xml that is used by the application

```
  <Environment name="CTClassFolder" type="java.lang.String" value="C:\TMP" />
```

How do I set this variable in Glassfish 2.1. I know there is an **asenv.conf** file in version 3, but I dont find anything like that in 2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bring up the server, log into the admin console, navigate to the JVM options, and add a -D paramater, then restart.

Answer (score 5):

g051051's answer is still valid in GF4/Payara :

In the admin console (http://localhost:4848), navigate to :

```
-Configuration
    -server-config
        -JVM Parameters
            -JVM Options
```

Then, add your parameter prefixed with -D, for instance :

```
-DBF_DIR_DOC=C:/BU/BF/BFdocuments
```

In your java code, you can retrieve the property easily :

```
String directory = System.getProperty("BF_DIR_DOC");
```

You're done.

Comment: For some strange reason I can't get read the JNDI variables using the InitialContext().lookup method.  But adding the config param to glassfishs' JVM Options worked!