# How to set a java:comp/env/foo JNDI variable in Glassfish 4.1?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jndi

I'd like to use a ServletFilter that reads it configuration from the java:comp/env/ JNDI namespace. As the value will be different on devel and production servers, it should not be hardcoded via  in web.xml but instead be configured in the application server.

I already tried the following places but none seemed to be right:

- System Properties
- Web Container / General Properties
- JVM Settings / Additional Properties (suggested in [How to set an env variable in Glassfish 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955924/how-to-set-an-env-variable-in-glassfish-2-1))
- Resource Connectors (didn't work)
- asenv.conf (only in Glassfish 2?)

How can I set a custom JNDI variable in Glassfish 4.1?

Comment: "the value will be different on [various] servers"... I'm a little unclear. The JNDI name is always the same, right? It's just that what it points to that will vary, right? Also, why specifically the "comp/env" namespace?

Comment: I would suggest you read Chapter 19 of the [GlassFish Administration Guide](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/administration-guide.pdf). There's even a section titled "Administering Custom JNDI Resources"!

Comment: @dcsohl: Thanks for your answers!

I meant: the key "java:comp/env/cas/serverName" stays the same, the value, which is a hostname, varies between devel and production AppServers.

I'd read that chapter in the Admin Guide before but the only example asked for a restype which was not further explained and a factory class whereas I only wanted to use a simple String... but the solution was much simpler, see below :)

Answer (score 1):

I installed only the Glassfish 4.1 Web Edition. While it has JNDI support, the web GUI comlpetely lacked the Resources -> JNDI menu to configure own variables!

In the Web Profile Glassfish, custom JNDI variables can be written in the domain.xml, they seem to survive other changes via the Admin GUI:

```
<resources>
  ...
  <custom-resource res-type="java.lang.String" jndi-name="cas/serverName" factory-class="org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory">
    <property name="value" value="https://sso.example.com/"></property>
  </custom-resource>
</resources>
...
<servers>
  <server name="server" config-ref="server-config">
    ...
    <resource-ref ref="cas/serverName"></resource-ref>
  </server>
</servers>
```

After adding a JNDI variable to Glassfish, it's only availble with InitialContext.doLookup("cas/serverName") though, not within the java:comp/env namespace. To get that, I had to add the following to my web.xml (it did not work in glassfish-web.xml!):

```
 <resource-ref>
   <res-ref-name>cas/serverName</res-ref-name> 
   <res-type>java.lang.String</res-type>
   <lookup-name>cas/serverName</lookup-name> 
 </resource-ref>
```

Comment: I had to add `<ResourceLink name="cas/serverName" global="cas/serverName" type="java.lang.String"/>` to _META-INF/context.xml_ as well to get it working.

Comment: @RandomFreeman: context.xml is Tomcat specific, Glassfish does not use it