# Where to set system variable for application running in glassfish 4

Tags: java, linux, service, glassfish, environment-variables

We are needing to set a system variable that our application can read that is being ran within Glassfish 4. The application is currently accessing the system variable with System.getenv().

We set an a system environment property in Windows like this:

```
App_Home=/opt/app/config
```

I have tried adding it to `glassfish/glassfish4/config/asenv.conf` but that didn't seem to work. I have done a bunch of searching and everything I keep running back into is setting a java property (e.g. this [How to set an env variable in Glassfish 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955924/how-to-set-an-env-variable-in-glassfish-2-1)). I am wanting to access the system property not a java property.

I have also tried setting the "System Properties" in the glassfish administration console under "Server (Admin Server) --> Properties --> System Properties" clicked "Add Property" and added my environment variable. However, the application still doesn't find it using System.getenv().

Comment: maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782467/system-getenv-returns-null-when-the-environment-variable-exists

Comment: I appreciate it but what I ended up doing was using the service "Environment" value in my glassfish.service file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use [Service Environment= option](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd.exec.html#Environment=) in my services file to resolve this.

Simply adding the following worked:

```
Environment="App_Home=..."
Environment="PYTHONPATH=..."
```